# simple example jspanel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i try to run the basic example of jspanel 2 but the weight is overflow

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jsPanel</title>

    <link href="src/jsPanel.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="src/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="src/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/jquery-ui-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/jquery.jspanel.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sample-basic' ).click(function(){
            $.jsPanel();
        });
    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <button id="sample-basic" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the pluggin
http://jspanel.de/

any jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to your code working in `jsfiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/czqa7gu8/

Just apply your css... Or ask what you really need from your css code.

Comment: thanks my fault was the order of the libraries 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsPanel.css" />