# open jspanel in minimized mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i am working on to add [jspanel](http://v1bs.jspanel.de/index.html) plugin  in my project, is there any way to open jspanel in minimized mode, i found some [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106494/simple-example-jspanel-2) related to, but could not find any right answer, here is sample code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspanel3/3.10.0/jquery.jspanel.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspanel3/3.10.0/jquery.jspanel-compiled.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function clickToOpen() {
     $.jsPanel({
    position: "left",
    size:     {width: 120, height: 270},
    overflow: {vertical: 'scroll'},
    theme:    "light",   
    });
    }   
    </script>
       <input type="button" value="click to open" onclick="clickToOpen()"></input> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample for version 4:

```
     jsPanel.create({
        content: "<p>minimized</p>",
        theme: 'info',
        position: "left-top",
        setStatus: 'minimized'
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [option.setStatus](http://jspanel.de/api/#option/setstatus) of jsPanel v3.x

```js
$.jsPanel({
    setstatus: "minimize"
});
```